# Excel marco vba - Checking of 1 and/or 2 cells for values

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA macro, but I'm tasked to create a project which is to let users input value(s) to the cell(s) in sheet 2, search through the data(sheet 1) and copy paste the filtered data to sheet 2.

Let say A and B are the values inputs. I tried

```
    For Row = 2 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 1).value = a And Cells(i, 2).value = b Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Copy
            Sheet2.Select
            Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            Sheet1.Select
        ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = A Or Cells(i, 2).Value = B Then
            Execute
        End If
    Next Row
    Sheet2.Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Range("B3").Select
```

If the user input 1 value, the result is correct. But if the user input both A and B, it should return those rows containing the 2 values, but instead it returned me A results and B results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: would you mind adding an example?

Comment: Hi user3598756. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing user enters the values `a` and/or `b` in `Sheet2` cells `A1` and `B1`. Basically, what you want is to ignore any of them if it is not entered. Try this:

```
Sub mysub()
    Dim i As Long, finalRow As Long, destRow As Long, a, b
    destRow = 2
    a = Sheet2.Range("A1").value ' <-- adjust to the place where user enters a
    b = Sheet2.Range("B1").value ' <-- and b
    With Sheet1
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To finalRow
            If (IsEmpty(a) Or .Cells(i, 1).value = a) And _
               (IsEmpty(b) Or .Cells(i, 2).value = b) Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 7).Copy
                Sheet2.Cells(destRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                destRow = destRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi A.S.H, thank you for your time to code out. I tested the codes, it returned me And but not the Or part. Means user need to input both in order to search. If 1 input will return nothing.

Comment: Is it possible that you have "space characters" in the non-entered cell? Also, when only b is entered in cell "B1", it should be fetched from only column `B` of `Sheet1`, right?

Comment: You mean if there are any character(s) in other cell, the program might not work? Yes. If I want to search for B, then it will search column B in Sheet1, same for A. If I want to search A and B, it should return me row(s) containing A and B.

Comment: If you enter only A, in Sheet2!A1, but you left B empty in Sheet2!B1, it will search for A only in column A of Sheet1? right?

Comment: Yes, it will search for those value(s) which the user input.

Comment: Well that's weird, it works perfectly in my tests. I wonder what is different in yours. Note that the code above seraches for an `exact equality`  of the values, it is *case sensitive* and doesn't do *partial matching*.

Comment: Perhaps just now got some error. Now I encountered was it only copied the last row of the correct result to the new sheet, but not all the rows containing the input.